# is this DIV layout possible with only CSS (without background image)?

Tags: css, layout

is this 6-edge layout possible with CSS only?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/rx1rba9msuxvwkc/sc.png

Thanks.

Comment: You should make this picture public. Currently, your link ask to log to Dropbox.

Comment: Please, include code in the question, use pictures only to support questions (and inline them using stack overflow's picture functionality), include attempted solutions and/or specific points you got stuck. This reads like a "fix my problem for me" question, which typically gets bad response.

Comment: @EricMORAND - that's not a Dropbox login, that's the picture he's linking to.

Comment: @PaulTomblin Now I feel stupid ! Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum you can do with pure `CSS` is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/eh2qA/

And:
* no borders on a "title" element
* no border radius on a "title" element
* no flexibility at all
* no support for all browsers

So I think your layout is impossible on pure CSS.